# Mmenu Jquery plugin - Page not scrollable after not choosing menu choice - & How to disable blue selection marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mmenu

I'm using the [MMenu jquery plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl), which I've found a little annoying bug, probably within my code.. Let's just hope not. The thing is: When I open the menu and not choosing a choice, but click on the menu anchor / body of the page, the menu collapses (like it should), but the page somehow doesn't become scrollable anymore. Like it's fixed. Even more strangely: I cannot reproduce this on the web, only on my phone, where the page is loaded as an iFrame - Could that perhaps be the cause? So I can't give you a live example..

And secondly, since it's such an easy question, I didn't want to waste asking another question for just this: How do you remove the selection area, when one selects text with the cursor, which is normally blue, and on [this website](http://newsourcing.nl) it's green. I want it to be either hidden or completely transparent.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Actually, the drawer did not close properly rendering that effect. And yes, only on Android. Anyway, I used the latest files, and the problem went away.

Previously a scroll div I made and having many items inside the drawer (that made drawer scrolling necessary) broke it which required a hack to overcome the problem. After I installed the latest files, remove the hack, everything still worked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, will re-download all files then and feedback ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: I can verify the issue has not been resolved. - Any thoughts?

Comment: I can think of one other but I can't guarantee - that is other js plugin's code is stopping it from working (but for me this happened only with mmenu's previous version).